# Component identification: 1600A NH & FBH5AA FDMP & W10B 89F

Tags: identification, components

Can't find the component by it number, they look like FETs on a fan PCB but need datasheet.

[image]
[image]
[image: 0]

Comment: are you trying to repair a fan?

Comment: Yes: 9BMC24P2G001, my psu went bad from nothing and inject 52V instead 24V. Already replaced a FET and a resistor on PWM circuit (brown cable), a diode on latch (yellow cable), i remove all resistor and diode to test them outside. Everything seens ok now but it wont draw power (20mah only) or spin. MCU is also outputing 5V to other parts so i guess it's good too. 1.2V on each phase. 0.6V on PWM (should be 24V)